# The plugins x, x and x use a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I know there's a bunch of questions for this same error, but none of them work for me. I was working on my app just fine and run `flutter build ipa`. That command failed and all of a sudden I could not even run the app again on the emulator. Android Studio is complaining about this when I try to run the app:

> The plugins `app_settings, connectivity_plus, device_info, device_info_plus, emoji_picker_flutter, firebase_analytics, firebase_auth, firebase_core, flutter_keyboard_visibility, flutter_native_splash, fluttertoast, in_app_review, location, mixpanel_flutter, package_info_plus, platform_device_id, share_plus, sign_in_with_apple` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding. 
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.

While the error message is pretty clear, it has not sense. For instance, `firebase_analytics` removed all usage of Android V1 embedding on 8.3.4 as seen here https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics/changelog. That's why I'm thinking there might be something else going on at my end that I can't figure out. Specially considering that the error appeared all of a sudden without upgrading anything at my end.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: are all these "`app_settings, connectivity_plus, device_info, device_info_plus, emoji_picker_flutter, firebase_analytics, firebase_auth, firebase_core, flutter_keyboard_visibility, flutter_native_splash, fluttertoast, in_app_review, location, mixpanel_flutter, package_info_plus, platform_device_id, share_plus, sign_in_with_apple`" packages latest?

Comment: Well, if I do the latest through flutter pub upgrade --major-versions they get reduced but is still incoherent. Would be this ones then: `device_info, emoji_picker_flutter, firebase_analytics, firebase_auth, firebase_core, flutter_keyboard_visibility, flutter_native_splash, fluttertoast, in_app_review, mixpanel_flutter, platform_device_id, share_plus,
sign_in_with_apple`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I noticed that all my libraries had an empty library file. Not sure what caused it, but what worked for me was on the project level sidebar `Project -> External Libraries -> Flutter Plugins -> On any plugin left click -> Open in -> Finder -> Delete all files`, which represent the cached plugins. Then, `pug get` and run your app again.